# when using GSAP and Locomotive, markers 'start' and 'end' are not fixed but move along with scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I'm making an simple animation in React project with GSAP and Locomotive. but I'm experiencing a problem where the start and end markers are not fixed and move along with the scroll. I think I've done GSAP and Locomotive settings well.
The strange thing is that when I scroll in the regular mode of codesandbox, the marker is fixed and works well. But when I click the 'toggle responsive preview' button in codesandbox and refresh, then try scrolling, the marker doesn't stay fixed and moves with the scroll. And in a real local environment outside of codesandbox, the marker also doesn't stay fixed and exhibits the same behavior, moving with the scroll.
May I know what's the problem??

**CodeSandBox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/locomotive-gsap-xsq7lf?file=/src/App.js

**Page.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";
import { gsap, ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/all";
import "../locomotiveStyle/locomotive-scroll.css";
import { Wrap } from "./PageStyle";
import One from "../components/one/One";
import Two from "../components/two/Two";

const Page = () => {
  const wrapRef = useRef(null);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const oneRef = useRef(null);
  const twoRef = useRef(null);

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  //locomotive setting
  useEffect(() => {
    const locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: document.querySelector(".container"),
      smooth: true
    });

    locoScroll.on("scroll", ScrollTrigger.update);

    ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy(".container", {
      scrollTop(value) {
        return arguments.length
          ? locoScroll.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)
          : locoScroll.scroll.instance.scroll.y;
      },
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        return {
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight
        };
      },

      pinType: document.querySelector(".container").style.transform
        ? "transform"
        : "fixed"
    });

    ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refresh", () => locoScroll.update());

    ScrollTrigger.refresh();
  }, []);

  //GSAP
  useEffect(() => {
    let tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: oneRef.current,
        start: "75% center",
        end: "105% center",
        scrub: true,
        markers: true
      }
    });

    tl.to(twoRef.current, {
      x: 300,
      duration: 5
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrap ref={wrapRef}>
      <div ref={containerRef} className="container">
        <One ref={oneRef} />
        <Two ref={twoRef} />
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

**One.jsx**
Two.jsx is same with One.jsx

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { Wrap } from "./OneStyle";

const One = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Wrap ref={ref}>
      <span>1</span>
    </Wrap>
  );
});

export default One;
```